# Routing some traffic through an Azure point-to-site vpn

Tags: vpn, routing, point-to-site-vpn

A client is setting up some AWS resources for people from my company to access. They are requiring that we setup a VPN so that they can whitelist just the gateway's public IP. I've setup an Azure VPN Gateway as per Microsoft's web instructions. I can connect to the VPN just fine. However, my IP address is still reported by whatismyip.com as my original IP address. How can I make all or some of the traffic from my clients route through the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible, as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916499/how-to-use-azure-vpn-as-a-proxy-gateway

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f1300322-8eee-4d2d-ae42-cafff52c1bb1/is-it-possible-to-route-all-client-internet-traffic-through-azure-pointtosite-vpn

I'll have to try a different approach.